# barcode generated with jasperreport can't be scanned

Tags: java, jasper-reports, barbecue

I'm working on a javafx project where i need to generate a label product with a barecode (code128).
I used jasperreport with barbecue library for this purpose.
The problem is that the barcode generated can't be scanned with my barcode scanner (metrologic MS9535).

Here is a sample of a label i'm generating:
[image: Label sample]

Please help.

Comment: See the **Dimensions** section of http://www.precisionid.com/code128-barcode-faq.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can read your barcode (with my smartphone) so, it seems to be a valid barcode, there could be many reasons why in your report the barcode is not readable.

#### Resolution

Your image is too small and the scanner can't read the barcode

#### Placement

Your image is placed to near to borders or other lines that make the barcode unreadable.

#### Configuration

Your scanner is not configured properly to read such barcode.

Try to print just the image you put as example (make it big enough at least 6 inches or 15cm) and see if you can read it.

Then maybe make it a bit taller, not everybody is sniper.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes i have already noticed that the barecode is readable by a smartphone or tablet but not with a scanner.
I will give it a try as you suggested. Thanks again.